# Node event emitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, stream

I am new to node and I was studying about event emitter and I created one demo program

```
var eventEmitter = new event.EventEmitter();
var fs = require("fs");
var data = '';

var read = fs.createReadStream("demo.txt");
read.setEncoding('UTF8');

read.on('data', function(resp) {  
    console.log(resp);
});

data='some data';
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("demo.txt");
writeStream.write(data,'UTF8');
writeStream.end();
writeStream.on('finish',function(){
    console.log("finish");
});
```

so the output is 'finish' but if I write the read stream after the write stream the output is 'finish some data' so why the read stream is not producing an output if I put it first.

PS: I already have data in the file

Comment: When you initialize the read stream, it starts flowing immediately.  If the file is empty at that point (or doesn't even exist yet), then it finishes and there's nothing to read.  It doesn't continue to watch the file and wait for more data to show up in the file.  It reads what is there and then its done.

Comment: but the file is there and the data is also there if I remove the write stream it works

Comment: Whenever streams aren't working as you expect, add an event handler for the `error` event and see what you get.

Comment: I have joined an error handler also but the output is still same

Comment: `fs.createWriteStream()` without any options creates a new empty file, replacing any previous file.  So, when you do `fs.createWriteStream("demo.txt")`, you kill any previous content in that file.  Thus when `fs.createReadStream()` gets around to trying to read some content, it just sees any empty file.  You can pass flags to `fs.createWriteStream()` to modify the file rather than replace it.

Comment: I have added flags to the write stream and yes the read stream then worked  but now the the output is 'resp finish some data' can you explain why it is executing the read stream twice

Comment: It would be better for you to describe what you're trying to accomplish and we could then help with best code to do that.  You have code that is, by nature of async timing, unpredictable so this is likely not a good way to solve any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jfriend00 correctly mentioned, you should first write file, then you can read it.

```
const fs = require("fs");

var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream("demo.txt");
writeStream.write('some data','UTF8');
writeStream.end();
writeStream.on('finish',function(){
  console.log("finish");

  let data = '';

  const read = fs.createReadStream("demo.txt", {encoding: 'UTF8'});

  read.on('data', function(resp) {  
    console.log(resp);
    data += resp;
  });
});
```

So, several points here:

- you don't actually use event emitter in this example on your own
- you can set encoding directly in `createReadStream` method